# app.js y app.css en Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Estoy intentando entender mejor Laravel Mix.

En un proyecto Laravel tenemos 2 archivos app.js, uno en la carpeta public/js para todo el funcionamiento básico y otro en resources/js donde se configura lo relacionado con Vue.

Ahora bien, Laravel Mix procesa y minifica archivos .js, esta configuración la hacemos en webpack.mix.js, por ejemplo:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', [
      //
      ]);
```

Hasta acá todo bien, pero no veo que procese los archivos .js y .css que están de antemano en public/js y public/css. Entonces, estos archivos se pueden agregar a Laravel Mix? Si se puede, de qué forma? O lo estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: para procesar los archivos se hacen mediante modulos, en este caso es webpack quien traspila esos modulos a ES5 que es el que puede interpretar tu navegador, mix.js recibe dos parametros el 1ro es el archivo a compilar y el 2do es la ruta a donde se va transferir el archivo compilado, para compilarlo no se puede hacer así como así, se debe correr un script mediante tareas ya se como gulp o similar, en este caso el ecosistema de node lo hace por ti, solo es necesario correr el script npm run dev desde un shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix procesa lo que tú le indiques que procese como entrypoints y él se mete de ahí hacia adentro haciendo que Webpack siga un conjunto de reglas. La mayoría viene preconfigurada y el archivo `webpack.mix.js` te permite customizar a gusto.

Tu archivo de configuración dice:

```
mix.js(
  // Toma el script en resources/js/app.js como entrypoint 
  "resources/js/app.js",
  // transpílalo a public/js/app.js incluyendo recursivamente sus dependencias
  "public/js/app.js"
  ).vue() // usa las reglas Vue osea incluye el template-compiler y eso...
  .sass(
     // luego toma los estilos desde el entrypoint "resources/sass/app.scss"
     "resources/sass/app.scss", 
     // y usa node-sass para convertirlo en public/css/app.css 
     // incluyendo otros estilos llamados con @import
     "public/css/app.css"
   );
```

Ten presente que la versión transpilada de `resources/js/app.js` o parte de ésta, **pisará** `public/js/app.js`. En general cualquier script o estilo que haya en `public` pueden ser efímeros.

```
└─ public
  └─ js
     └─ app.js // lógica existente
└─ resources
  └─ js 
     └─ app.js // lógica nueva
     └─ App.vue
```

Yo sugeriría:

1. Renombra tu archivo, (por ejemplo a current.js) con eso evitas que lo pise mix.
2. Mueve tu archivo a `resources/js` (con otro nombre, para no chocar con lo que tienes en app.js), de modo que tus scripts de origen siempre están en resources y lo que haya en public no se edite a mano
3. Usa mix para copiar ese archivo desde su nueva ubicación a public, sin alterarlo

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
  .copy('resources/js/current.js','public/js/current.js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Quedando

```
└─ public
  └─ js
     └─ <VACIO, se llena con mix>
└─ resources
  └─ js 
     └─ app.js // lógica nueva
     └─ current.js // lógica existente
     └─ App.vue
```

Dependiendo del contenido de tu lógica actual más adelante podrás integrarla a la nueva, pero primero haz funcionar lo crucial.

Comment: Clarísimo, muchas gracias.